# Successive Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is given as

"Find a single matrix that reflects y=x, then rotates about the origin through $\pi$."

I know that the matrix for y=x would be  $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$.

What would the matrix be for rotating about the origin through $\pi$, and the "single matrix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation matrix of angle $\theta$ is:
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

If the reflection matrix is $A$, then both succesive transformations can be written as a single matrix (i.e. only one matrix) by multiplying: $C=B \cdot A$.